# Stored procedure multiple inserts error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm writing a simple stored procedure in SQL Server 2016 but when I have 2 insert statements I keep getting an error that says

> Incorrect syntax near 'End'

Is there something wrong with my syntax or is this not possible?

Note that it is a table-valued parameter that I am sending into the stored procedure as arguments

SQL statement:

```
-- This is the stored procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SampleProcedure]
    ( -- which accepts 2 table value parameters
      -- It should be noted that the parameter is readonly
     @Sample As [dbo].[SampleDataType] Readonly, 
     @Rec As [dbo].[SampleRecType] ReadOnly
    )
AS
BEGIN
    -- We simply insert values into the DB table from the parameter
    -- The table value parameter can be used like a table with only read rights

    -- INSERT INTO SampleTable(SampleString, SampleDate)
    --     SELECT SampleString, SampleDate 
    --     FROM @Sample

    INSERT INTO tbl1Recipients(strEmailSendIDx, strEmailAddress, strDisplayName, strRecipientType)
    INSERT INTO tbl1SentEmails(strEmailSendID, dtmSent, strSubject, strBody, strConversationID, strConversationTopic, strConversationIndex, dtmReplied, dtmOpened, dtmClicked, blnTrackOpens, blnTrackClicks, blnTrackReplies, lngMergeID, blnHide, lngLatestEventID, strClickResponse, dtmClickResponse)
        SELECT * 
        FROM @Sample 
END
```

Edited, after reading the comments and the suggested  answer this is what solved the issue:

```
-- This is the stored procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SampleProcedure]
    (
    -- which accepts one table value parameter. 
    -- It should be noted that the parameter is readonly
    @Sample As [dbo].[SampleDataType] Readonly, 
    @Rec As [dbo].[SampleRecType] ReadOnly
    )
AS
BEGIN
    -- We simply insert values into the DB table from the parameter
    -- The table value parameter can be used like a table with only read rights

    INSERT INTO tbl1Recipients(strEmailSendID, strEmailAddress, strDisplayName, strRecipientType)
        SELECT * 
        FROM @Rec

    INSERT INTO tbl1SentEmails(strEmailSendID, dtmSent, strSubject, strBody, strConversationID, strConversationTopic, strConversationIndex, dtmReplied, dtmOpened, dtmClicked, blnTrackOpens, blnTrackClicks, blnTrackReplies, lngMergeID, blnHide, lngLatestEventID, strClickResponse, dtmClickResponse)
        SELECT * 
        FROM @Sample 
END
```

All it needed was another `SELECT` after I entered the data into `tbl1Recipients`

Comment: in short, your syntax is wrong. Please check the syntax of your INSERT statement

Comment: @Squirrel if I remove the `Insert` for `tbl1Recipients` it works. I do know that multiple inserts are allowed...but I checked the values for `tbl1Recipients` and it seems okay.

Comment: Your insert statement looks wrong. The results from the select * from '@sample should not be able to fit into both a table with 4 columns and another table with 18 columns. You should be able to separate the two insert statements with two different select result sets, maybe build a '@samplerecipients and a '@sampleemails

Comment: What values for tbl1Recipients did you check? There aren't any. Are you trying to feed @Sample into two different tables in one go? That definitely is syntactically incorrect and besides you need an explicit column list in your select to match up to the inserted columns

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, yeah I was attempting to do exactly that.

Comment: @BasicIsaac, reading from the answer and your comment I'm going to do what you just suggested. I don't think I'll be able to do what I originally wanted to do.. Have one sample and attempt to enter into both of the tables.

Comment: A word of warning: using `select *` means your stored procedure will break if the columns ever change in this table. *Never* do insert/select without explicitly listing the insert and select columns.

Answer (score 1):

This is your first `insert`:

```
Insert Into tbl1Recipients(strEmailSendIDx, strEmailAddress, strDisplayName, strRecipientType)
Select * From @Rec
```

What is expected next is `VALUES` or `SELECT`.  The next token is `INSERT`, and that just doesn't make sense.

You need to include the data you want to insert.